# Cannot open database "dbname" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a connection to sql server database(hosted on localhost) but keep getting the error mentioned in the title.

```
    Application("ConnectionString") = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=yes;UID=dbadmin; PWD=dbadmin" 
Application("ConnectionTimeout") = 15
Application("CommandTimeout") = 90
Application("CursorLocation") = 3

strQuery = "select * from dec_users"
Set objDBConnection = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

objDBConnection.open Application("ConnectionString")
Set RS = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

RS.Open strQuery, objDBConnection
```

any ideas?

Comment: Maybe no permissions for user?

Comment: i used the sa login and also this login. dbadmin is set to be able to write and write from the database.

Comment: but Trusted_Connection=yes is saying to use the windows login information instead of the UID/PWD combination. Does the windows user you're running this code under have access to the database?

Comment: ok. i've removed truested_connection=yes and now I'm gettgin the error: Microsoft OLE DB Provider for SQL Server (0x80040E4D)
Login failed for user 'ypoadmin'.

Comment: Was the database created on that particular server or copied & attached?

Comment: no it wasn't moved..it's just recently been created onto the webserver. I'm wondering if it webserver permissions to read from the database. found this article but not quite sure how to go about rectifying it: http://www.experts-exchange.com/Web_Development/Web_Languages-Standards/ASP/Q_24041785.html

Comment: actually not that may not be a good example I've just posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are putting it wrong, change to:

```
Application("ConnectionString") = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;
        Persist Security Info=False;User ID=dbadmin;Initial Catalog=mydb;
        Data Source=localhost\SQLExpress;Password=dbadmin"
```

(Linebreaks added for legibility)

When in doubt, create a .UDL file, construct the ConnectionString using the GUI, and then copy paste the ConnectionString (opening the file with notepad)

Comment: ok created the udl file...and was finally able to connect. came across another glitch and think it was due to the sqlserver browser services not running. able to connect, read and write now.